# Get current directory in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to construct a file path in order to read an XSLT file, like so:

```
string path = "../_xslt/example.xslt";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
```

...where I am in a controller (/Controllers/ExampleController.cs), and the '/_xslt/' folder is at the same level as '/Controllers'

However, the error I am getting is:

> (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
>   Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\_xslt\example.xslt'.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method to map any relative paths for you, in your controller this is easily accessible via the `ControllerContext`:

```
string path = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/_xslt/example.xslt");
...
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string TestX()
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // You get main rott
    string dirc = ""; // just var for use
    string[] pathes = Directory.GetDirectories(path); // get collection

    foreach (string str in pathes)
    {
        if (str.Contains("NameYRDirectory")) // paste yr directory
        {
            dirc = str;
        }
    }

    return dirc; // after use Method and modify as you like
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If controller is present at directory root

```
String path = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/_xslt/example.xslt");
```

Else

```
String path = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"../_xslt/example.xslt");
```